# Passing general variables as arguments of the constructor in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Service in a Bundle that behaves differently based on a integer variable (allowed values : 0/1).

When I use the service for example in a Symfony Command using the following "get" function

`$handle = $this->get('test.serve');`

How do I pass a simple integer variable to the Constructor of the Service as an argument ?

Comment: You don't.  The service definition is self contained so get does not allow passing parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of services is for them to be constructed **only once** and be reused everytime they are called.

You can use a setter to change that value (have default be 0) so it will modify the behavior of the service.

EDIT: A service also isn't supposed to behave differently, it has one and only purpose. You might consider separating into 2 services which inherit shared code (never repeat yourself).

Answer (score 0):

most people add init method to service class that that works to bypass this problem

you can't do that by service get method.